# como puedo incluir un variable dentro de comillas dobles

Tags: php, mysql, php7

```
$articulos= $conexion->prepare(
          'SELECT SQL_CALC_ROWS * FROM  articulos LIMIT $inicio, $postPorPaginas'
);
```

Cuando esta así dentro de php me aparece como si fuese una simple cadena 
aunque yo haya declarado la varible con sus valores

Comment: Dices que las variables te aparecen como _parte de_ la cadena y no como las variables en si?

Comment: Eso es porque las comillas simple no toman el valor de las variables para ellas todo es texto en cambio las comillas dobles si toman el valor de las variables y tu estas usando comillas simples en ves de dobles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ese "prepare" que tenes puesto en tu codigo me hace pensar que estas usando PDO:

Por lo cual lo recomendable seria lo siguiente:

```
$articulos= $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_ROWS * FROM articulos LIMIT :inicio, :post_por_paginas");

$articulos->bindParam(':inicio', $inicio);
$articulos->bindParam(':post_por_paginas', $postPorPaginas);

$articulos->execute();
```

De esta manera ademas estas evitando sufrir inyección de SQL

En caso de que no estes usando PDO, te recomendaria que le des una mirada [acá](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!! por tu aporte

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar variables en cadenas de caracteres en PHP hay distintas formas como se indica en la documentación de PHP.

[Documentación Cadenas de caracteres PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Para el ejemplo uso la forma [Sintaxis compleja (llaves)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) que se basa en cadenas encerradas por `"` (comillas dobles) y encerrando la variable en `{}` llaves:

```
<?php

$inicio = 1;
$postPorPaginas = 10;

$articulos = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_ROWS * FROM articulos LIMIT {$inicio}, {$postPorPaginas}");
```

De esta manera el editor de texto o IDE mostrará correctamente las variables dentro de la cadena de caracteres.

Comment: Eso es la interpolación de strings en comillas dobles. [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) es otra sintaxis diferente: `<<<EJEMPLO` `texto` `EJEMPLO;`

Comment: @Mariano gracias por la aclaración, realmente en la documentación de PHP indica que cuando se usan `{}` para agregar una variable en comillas dobles también es _heredoc_, pero he realizado la debida corrección en la respuesta, gracias.

Comment: No encontré dónde... Fijate que lo llama [Sintaxis compleja (llaves)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Answer (score 2):

Es correcto lo que dice @LeonardeCabré en su respuesta.

Si estás usando PDO (o MySQLi), todas las consultas que manejen variables externas debes pasarlas a través de consultas preparadas para evitar la inyección de código malicioso.

Solamente quiero señalar que con PDO puedes simplificar el código, ahorrándote los `bindParam` y pasando los parámetros como un array, en el `execute`.

El Manual de PHP habla sobre esa segunda posibilidad, la cual, pienso, explotamos muy poco:

> ### `execute`
>
> Ejecuta la sentencia preparada. Si ésta incluía marcadores de
>   parámetros, se debe:
>
> - llamar a `PDOStatement::bindParam()` y/o `PDOStatement::bindValue()` para vincular variables o valores
>     (respectivamente) a los marcadores de parámetros. Las variables
>     vinculadas pasan su valor como entrada y reciben el valor de salida,
>     si lo hubiera, de sus marcadores de parámetros asociados
> - **o pasar un array de valores de parámetros de sólo entrada**
>
> <sub>❯ Fuente: [`execute` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)</sub>

Veamos dos ejemplos:

#### Con marcadores de `:nombre`

```
$strSQL='SELECT SQL_CALC_ROWS * FROM  articulos LIMIT :inicio, :postPorPaginas';
$articulos= $conexion->prepare($strSQL);
$arrParams=array(':inicio'=>$inicio, ':postPorPaginas'=>$postPorPaginas);
$articulos->execute($arrParams);
```

---

#### Con marcadores de posición `?`

```
$strSQL='SELECT SQL_CALC_ROWS * FROM  articulos LIMIT ?, ?';
$articulos= $conexion->prepare($strSQL);
$arrParams=array($inicio, $postPorPaginas);
$articulos->execute($arrParams);
```

Saber esto es particularmente útil, cuando tenemos que pasar muchos parámetros, o cuando los parámetros que intervienen en la consulta son dinámicos. Nos evitará invocar constantemente a `bindParam`, nos facilitará el proceso de construir una consulta que dependa de varios factores. La consulta ejecutada así es igualmente segura que cuando usamos `bindParam`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a sustituir las comillas simples por comillas dobles para que PHP interprete las variables y utiliza comillas simples para encerrar cada una de las variables de la consulta.

Comment: Revisa [¿Como Responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - Para que tus respuestas tengan una mejor aceptación y mejor claridad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_ROWS * FROM articulos LIMIT ".$inicio.", ".$postPorPaginas;
$articulos = $conexion->prepare($query);
```

Creo que esto es lo correcto, si usas comillas simples tan sólo cámbialas por lo que te pongo con comillas dobles. Espero que te ayude.